# Jquery get contents from a table into Facebook Feed Dialog on Click

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a table which lists all events on a debating calendar.  Each row has basic info such as the schools, the time and the venue etc.  I want to get it so that the last column in the table the share link is done via jquery so I don't need to do it for each entry. [See what I have so far here.](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/PhbXQ/)

I want to get it so that on click of the share link I get the relevant information for that row into a url like the below which opens in a new window so the user can post to facebook.  In the below I have the name of the class I want to appear in each spot eg .yearlevel I want the contents of the yearlevel class in the caption field.  Further complicating matters I need to make sure any spaces are encoded eg %20 to make the url valid.

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=123050457758183&
link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=School%20Debate&
caption=.yearlevel&
description=.homeschool%20.versus%20.awayschool%20@%20.venue%20@%20.datetime&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Is this possible?
Any pointers to get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you construct your url while you are creating rows of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) for each a href tag
and [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var homeschool = $(this).parent().siblings('.homeschool');


   var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?' + 'app_id=123050457758183&' + 'link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&' + 'picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&' + 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(homeschool) + 'caption=yearlevel&' + 'description=homeschool%20.versus%20.awayschool%20@%20.venue%20@%20.datetime&' + 'redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response';

   window.open(
   url, '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
   );

});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/69dDm/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this works thanks.  I am not quite sure how `var homeschool = $(this).parent().siblings('.homeschool');` works though so I set up variable for each item I wanted in there eg `var datetime = $('.datetime').html();`