# Get contents of a table row and post on Facebook with a share button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a basic table on my website which displays the following data in 5 tds in one row:

- Event Date
- Event time
- Event Type
- Event Location
- Event Organiser

I want to add one final td in the row with a Facebook share button in it, so that the content of the entire row can be shared on Facebook.

I found another SO post which I've tried to tailor to my own but can't seem to get it to work.
[ORIGINAL STACK OVERFLOW POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395709/jquery-get-contents-from-a-table-into-facebook-feed-dialog-on-click). It opens the dialog box but with an error. Can anyone tell me how this would be done? I no doubt have lots of issues, but any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$('.fb').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).parent().siblings('.type');


    var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?' + 'app_id=1498631000398156' + 'link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&' + 'picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&' + 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(type) + 'caption=date&' + 'description=.type%20on%20.date%20@%20.time%20.location%20organised%20by%20.organiser&' + 'redirect_uri=http://www.my-website.co.uk';

    window.open(
    url, '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="events-list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            </tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>DATE</td>
              <td>TIME</td>
              <td>TYPE</td>
              <td>LOCATION</td>
              <td>ORGANISER</td>
              <td>SHARE</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="date">27-November-2014</td>
              <td class="time">20.30 - 22.00</td>
              <td class="type">Opportunity Event</td>
              <td class="location">Tapas Bar La Trinca</td>
              <td class="organiser">Stephanie</td>
              <td class="share"><a class="fb" href="#" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can share on Facebook is a URL.

And within that URL you can have anything you want, and Facebook cares only if that URL exists and if it has some Graph Meta Tags, it has a better clue what's in it.

Which means you have to setup your Application, which I have no clue what you're using on Backend, and create a Route which holds a single Row data, eg : http://example.com/datas/1 where 1 is the ID of that ROW and when it asked it responds only with it's data.

This way you can share a URL on Facebook of each Row.

PS : But you can Post on someone else Feed anything you want, and to do so you have to use Facebook API, instead if doing a simple HTTP Cal on Facebook Dialog Object.

Hope that it makes sense.